# ml kit - Text Recognition output issues

Tags: firebase-mlkit

I am creating a business card app using the ml kit text recognition. I have an app  this is up and working, but have found that when uploading a business card and extracting the text, but the text comes back in a mess of clumps with no spaces.

I need to literally extract the text line by line.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

When the recognition operation succeeds, a `FirebaseVisionText` object will be passed to the success listener. A **FirebaseVisionText object contains the full text recognized in the image and zero or more TextBlock objects**.

Each `TextBlock` represents a rectangular block of text, which contains zero or more Line objects. Each Line object contains zero or more Element objects, which represent words and word-like entities (dates, numbers, and so on).

> For each TextBlock, Line, and Element object, you can get the text recognized in the region and the bounding coordinates of the region.

For example:

```
val resultText = result.text
for (block in result.textBlocks) {
    val blockText = block.text
    val blockConfidence = block.confidence
    val blockLanguages = block.recognizedLanguages
    val blockCornerPoints = block.cornerPoints
    val blockFrame = block.boundingBox
    for (line in block.lines) {
        val lineText = line.text
        val lineConfidence = line.confidence
        val lineLanguages = line.recognizedLanguages
        val lineCornerPoints = line.cornerPoints
        val lineFrame = line.boundingBox
        for (element in line.elements) {
            val elementText = element.text
            val elementConfidence = element.confidence
            val elementLanguages = element.recognizedLanguages
            val elementCornerPoints = element.cornerPoints
            val elementFrame = element.boundingBox
        }
    }
}
```

Source: [MLKit documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text#2.-extract-text-from-blocks-of-recognized-text)